# relative layout mess up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I use the layout below to show a list, in list item from left to right, it has an icon, title and subtitle and an imageView.

I put an icon and a progressbar in a container which also contains subtitle, you can see the code. What confused me a lot is the layout messed up.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_entry_container_height"
                android:padding="@dimen/list_item_entry_container_padding">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_space"
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_item_icon"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="abs__action_menu_overflow_descriptionabs__verflow_description"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/list_item_entry_title_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/list_item_entry_title_text_size"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_item_space"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/list_item_action"/>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_item_subtitle_group"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list_item_title"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_item_title"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_item_action"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_item_space">
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_download_status_icon"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_entry_download_icon_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_entry_download_icon_height"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_item_entry_download_icon_margin_left"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/list_item_entry_download_icon_margin_top"
                android:src="@drawable/list_item_download_ok"/>
        <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/list_item_download_status_progressbar"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_entry_download_progressbar_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_entry_download_progressbar_height"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_item_entry_download_progressbar_margin_left"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/list_item_entry_download_progressbar_margin_top"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_item_download_status_icon"
                android:visibility="visible"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_subtitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="abs__action_menu_overflow_description"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_item_download_status_progressbar"
                android:textColor="@color/list_item_entry_subtitle_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/list_item_entry_subtitle_text_size"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_action"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_entry_action_width"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and now it looks like this.
[image]
the title and subtitle messed up.

The right one that I want is like this
[image]

Anyone can help, thanks in advance!

Comment: use linear layout to build the list item(use weights) and populate in a listview, thats the best way.

Comment: @Dhina even I changed the root container to be LinearLayout, it still messy. The the indention of title and subtile in some items layout is not the same with others. really weried

Comment: finally I found the error, it was caused by someone wrote the padding in java code, so the xml code does\`t work anymore